# which one to use with this XML document (sequense, all or choice )

Tags: xml, xsd

please i have tag called PLAT that can contain the VIANDE tag once more that once and the LEGUMES tag all these tags can appear in any order
I tried to use sequence but they will appear in in order, all to appear in any order but the a tag can't appear more than once, about Choice the problem is that just an element that can appear

Salade

```
    <PLAT> Plat du jour: Poulet
        <VIANDE>Omelette</VIANDE>
        <LEGUMES>Frites</LEGUMES>
        <VIANDE>Poulet</VIANDE>
    </PLAT>
    <DESSERT>Tartelette</DESSERT>
</MENU>
<MENU jour="mardi">
    <ENTREE>Pâté</ENTREE>
    <PLAT> Plat du jour: Lapin
        <LEGUMES>Frites</LEGUMES>
        <VIANDE>Poulet</VIANDE>
    </PLAT>
    <DESSERT>Banane</DESSERT>
</MENU>
```

What i want to do is that VIANDE can appear once or more and LEGUMES just once but any order

here is my XML Schema

```
<xs:element name="MENUS">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MENU">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="ENTREE" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="PLAT">
                            <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                <xs:all  >
                                    <xs:element name="VIANDE" type="xs:string" />
                                    <xs:element name="LEGUMES" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:all>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="DESSERT" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="jour" type="jourSemaine" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question, [format your code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), write coherently, discover the period key, and at least pretend to respect the time of those you're hoping will help you.

Comment: @kjhunghes, Thank your for you suggestion. I guess it is clear, i don't know where is the problem.

Comment: One problem is that the words in the question do not form English sentences.  Most readers of Stack Overview are patient with non-native speakers and will try to puzzle out the meaning anyway, but that proves impossible here, because (second problem) this question does not use full stops to separate what are intended to be separate sentences.  The result is that at least some readers (e.g. me) will have no idea what you are trying to say.  The third problem is that your code is illegible because it's badly indented.  The fourth problem:  problems 1-3 suggest you are a time sink.

Answer (score 0):

> What i want to do is that VIANDE can appear once or more and LEGUMES
>   just once but any order

You can add `minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"` to LEGUMES and `minOccurs="1"` to VIANDE

Your XML

```
<MENUS>
<MENU jour="mardi">
<ENTREE>Pâté</ENTREE>
<PLAT> Plat du jour: Lapin
    <LEGUMES>Frites</LEGUMES>
    <VIANDE>Poulet</VIANDE>
</PLAT>
<DESSERT>Banane</DESSERT>
</MENU>
</MENUS>
```

Desired XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MENUS" type="MENUSType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="MENUType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ENTREE"/>
      <xs:element type="PLATType" name="PLAT"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="DESSERT"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="jour"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="PLATType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="LEGUMES" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="VIANDE" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="MENUSType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="MENUType" name="MENU"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```